# Hope pro 4 rear hub wear

Tags: hub, rear-wheel, wear

When I removed the Shimano 5800 cassette from the Hope 4 Pro hub I noticed that there is a significant axial play of the freehub body. Also I am able to slightly twist the driveside spacer from side to side. The hub have seen 3000 km. The QR was loose when I was removing the wheel. I replaced the cassette, mounted the wheel and tightened the QR properly.

[image]

The freehub body play disappeared and the hub seems to roll well, there are no unusual sounds when I ride the bike. But I plan the 3000+ km trip with approx. 15 kg of additional load and I want to know whether I can rely on this hub. I don't know its internals. Is there anything inside that can break after further equal amount of wear and stop me in the middle of nowhere?

**Edit:**
I found the [exploded view](http://www.hopetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Pro-4-Rear-Hub-Assembly.pdf) of the hub

What may cause the play of the freehub body? Maybe I closed QRs too tight and the axial load damaged the bearings?

Comment: I'd take the hub apart and check the bearings and axle. The end caps pull off and the freehub body pulls out of the hub.  You can check the internal bearings and the axle. If any of the bearing are siezed or very notchy then they need replaced.  All of the parts are replaceable and if anything is broken rather than worn out contact Hope, their warranty is very good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no circlips securing the bearings on the axle tube. The QR endcaps should be held in the axle by their o-rings. If these have been allowed to move apart (e.g by an inadequate or loose skewer), the overall width of the knurled surfaces that contact the frame will be more than 135mm. Assuming no damage to the endcaps or axle, pushing these back in should be enough.